Черный экран при переходе на страницу с Яндекс картой
После обновления flutter до 3.27 в Андроид приложении, при переходе на страницу, где находиться карта на мнгновение появляется  черный экран. Скорее всего связано с тем, что
Impeller теперь по умолчанию.

Так идите к разработчику карты и напишите это ему. Почему вы решили задать вопрос тут?
